# How to fix "could not find function read.socrata" when exporting to a PDF in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, socrata

I'm using R to import 2012 Maryland traffic data in json format.  The code works from the console but when I try to generate a PDF in R Markdown I receive the message below.  Any suggestions for how to correct?  R Markdown has worked well for the past month and one suggestion I found was to install MacTex but I'm concerned this may break R Markdown. I already have LaTeXit, TeXShop, Tex Live Utility and Excalibur installed.

Error in read.socrata("https://opendata.maryland.gov/resource/pdvh-tf2u.json") : 
  could not find function "read.socrata"
Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Comment: Have you loaded the package in the RMarkdown document? I.e put `library(RSocrata)` in the first chunk, just as you would load it in the console?

Comment: Thanks, Wil for the quick response.  Reloading MacTeX fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to an update to R Markdown that required me to reinstall MacTeX which fixed the issue.